# Python - Check if letter appears in consecutive words

Tags: python, regex, list

I have a task where I need to read input and check if that input occurs in some words. For example:

```
Who are your friends? Fred Bill Sue Simone
What is the message? Should you make tea?
Sue could have written this.
```

It prints "Sue could have written this because the letters "S", "U" and "E" appear in the each consecutive word. Another example is:

```
Who are your friends? James Nicky Jake
What is the message? join and make enough cash today!
James could have written this.
Jake could have written this.
```

Both names are printed because both of their letters appear consecutively in each word. I have the following code:

```
friends = input("Who are your friends? ").split()
message = input("What is the message? ").split()

name = []
other = []

for friend in friends:
  for f in friend.lower():
    for word in message:
      print("checking if", f, "is in", word.lower())
      if f in word.lower():
        print("Adding", f, " to name list")
        name.append(f)
        break
      else:
        other.append(f)
        continue

joinedResult = ''.join(name)

for person in friends:
  if person.lower() in joinedResult:
    print(person, "could have written this.")
```

It works perfect for the first example, but for the second example it prints all three names:

```
James could have written this.
Nicky could have written this.
Jake could have written this.
```

I have learnt that the code does not check if the letters in the name appear **consecutively**, rather it checks if the name is in any word. How do i solve this?

Comment: What will be the output of second example if there's another word before  `join`, say: 'zzz'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def find_char(string, char):
    start_index = 0
    while True:
        yield string.lower().find(char, start_index)  # checks for the char in the string
        start_index += 1  # increments the index to find further in the word, 
        # eg: 
        # Bob constructed[index 0]
        # ob constructed[index 1]
        # b constructed[index 2]


def find_it(friends, message):
    friends = friends.split()
    for friend in friends:
        sequence_check = []
        for char in friend.lower():
            gen = find_char(message, char)  # creates the find_char generator
            for _ in message:  # limits the search to the length of the word
                char_index = next(gen) # try to find the index
                if char_index not in sequence_check: # if not in the sequence
                    sequence_check.append(char_index) # add it to it
                    break
        if -1 in sequence_check: # this check if every character of the name is in the word
            continue
        if sorted(sequence_check) == sequence_check: # this part check if it's in a sequence.
            print (friend + ' could have written ' + message)


find_it('James Nicky Jake', "join and make enough cash today!")
find_it('Fred Bill Sue Simone', "Should you make tea?")
find_it("Bob", "Bob constructed Balloon Town")
```

Outputs:

```
James could have written join and make enough cash today!
Jake could have written join and make enough cash today!
Sue could have written Should you make tea?
Bob could have written Bob constructed Balloon Town
```

Redone it totally, much cleaner now.

The most work is done in the find_char function, which is a generator that reduced it's search space in each iteration, so it won't find place 'Bob' as [0,1,0], but [0,1,2] in the sequence.

Any question, feel free to ask.

Comment: If friends = "Fred Bill Sue Simone" and the message = "Should you make tea?" 
The output is: Bill could have written this Sue could have written this.
Desired output: Sue could have written this

Comment: Forgot to check if letters of the name are in the input. Hold on, will fix that.

Comment: I am getting a syntax error for  if sorted(sequence_check) == sequence_check "".join(letters) == friend.lower():. Near "".join(letters)

Comment: Was missing an 'and'. ;)

Comment: Does not work for: friends = Fred Bill Sue Simone and message = Should you make tea?. Output should be: Sue could have written this. Your code outputted nothing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66307/discussion-between-user3036519-and-f-rodrigues).

Comment: Sorry all the small mistakes, it's late night here. fixed both errors. Was forgeting to use word.lower() in the find.

Comment: SyntaxError: can't assign to function call. Occurs near word.lower()

Comment: friend = bob and message = Bob constructed Balloon Town. Your code outputs nothing, it was meant to output: bob could have written this

Comment: This one is nastier, when word.find(f) is looking for 'b', it doesn't take into account if the b is the first or the second, the sequence_check is set to [0, 1, 0], which is not sorted. I'll try to make up for that.

Comment: I guess I got all bases covered now.

Comment: AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'next'

Comment: what version of python are you using? Here's it's working fine.

Comment: use next(gen) instead of gen.next() for python 3.x.x

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all):

```
friends = input("Who are your friends? ").split()
message = input("What is the message? ").lower().split()

for friend in friends:
  if len(friend) <= len(message):
    if all(x in y for x, y in zip(friend.lower(), message)):
        print(friend, "could have written this.")
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> 
Who are your friends? Fred Bill Sue Simone
What is the message? Should you make tea?
Sue could have written this.
>>> 
Who are your friends? James Nicky Jake
What is the message? join and make enough cash today!
James could have written this.
Jake could have written this.
```

Comment: If friends = "Anastasia" and message = "and in another story, ants activated super ions!". The output is: Anastasia could have written this. The program should not have outputted anything as "Anastasia" does not appear in all the words.

Comment: @user3036519 I see what you meant, in that case `zip()` is not enough, go for `itertools.zip_longest`.

Comment: friend = bob and message = Bob constructed Balloon Town. Your code outputs nothing, it was meant to output: bob could have written this

Comment: @user3036519 How about now?

Comment: Excellent, but there's one case when it won't work: say the first word in the message won't match any first letter in any name, like: 'dummyword join and make enough cash today!' in your second example

Comment: @chapelo Agreed, [I asked for the same thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27329063/python-check-if-letter-appears-in-consecutive-words/27329392#comment43116862_27329063) earlier but OP haven't clarified that yet.

Answer (score 2):

Using **regex expression** could be a bit easier:

```
friends = raw_input("Who are your friends? ").split()
message = raw_input("What is the message? ").lower()

name = []
other = []

for friend in friends:
    regStr = '\w*\s?' + ''.join(['\w*' + f + '\w*\s' for f in friend.lower()])
    if re.match(regStr, message):
        name.append(friend)

for friend in name:
    print friend + " could have written this."
```

The regex pattern likes: `\w*\s?(s)\w*\s\w*(u)\w*\s\w*(e)\w*` for *friend* `Sue`

Testcase:

`Shoulde i?` [no match] (**sue** found but not consecutively => `[S]ho[u]ld[e] i?`)

`Should I make tea?` [no match]

`Should u make tea?` [sue]

Answer (score 1):

Note to my understanding you mean the n'th letter in their name must appear in the n'th word in the message. Maybe I'm wrong about this and you can clarify.

You need to pair each letter in their name with a word from the message, then check for inclusion. You can do this using `zip`

```
friends = 'James Nicky Jake'.split()
message = 'join and make enough cash today!'.split()

names = []
others = []

for friend in friends:
    match = True
    length = len(friend)

    for letter, word in zip(friend.lower(), message):
        if not letter in word.lower():
            match = False
            break

    if match:
        names.append(friend)
    else:
        others.append(friend)

for person in names:
        print(person, "could have written this.")
```

Comment: If friends = "Anastasia" and message = "and in another story, ants activated super ions!". The output is: Anastasia could have written this. The program should not have outputted anything as "Anastasia" does not appear in all the words.

Answer (score 0):

```
friends=["James","Nicky","Jake"]
words=["James could have written this","Jake could have written this"]
for friend in friends:
    for word in words:
        for name in word.split():
            if friend.lower()==name.lower():
                print friend,"yes"
            else:
                print friend,"no"
```

You can use this simple code rather than comparing `letter` by `letter` which is also prone to errors as letters can be anywhere in string not necessarily continous.

Comment: The input is meant to be: join and make enough cash today!. If i replace what you have stored in words with the input, it doesnt work.

Comment: @user3036519 bring your input to the format i have used.And then use the code.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what OP is looking for, to my understanding X is a possible author if the n'th letter in their name appears in the n'th word in message (for all n).

Answer (score 0):

## Code

```
def whosdoneit(names,message):
    good_names = []
    l_m = len(message)
    for name in names:
        if len(name) > l_m: continue
        if all(c.lower() in word.lower() for c, word in zip(name, message)):
            good_names.append(name)
    return good_names

print whosdoneit('Fred Bill Sue Simone'.split(),
                 'Should you make tea?'.split())

print whosdoneit('James Nicky Jake'.split(),
                 'join and make enough cash today!'.split())
```

## Output

```
['Sue']
['James', 'Jake']
```

## Commentary

The function returns a list of good names, people that could have written the para-acrostic  containing their name, so

- we start initializing the list to the null list

next we observe that no name longer than the number of words in the message can fit the requirements, so, to use it later,

- we compute and save the length, in words, of the message

Now,

- we loop over the list `names` to verify if `name` fits the rules

  - if the name is too long, no further processing
  - using `zip`, we construct a list of pairs, character `c` in `name`, `word` in `message`, and we construct a list of booleans using list comprehension
  - if `all` the booleans are true (`all` and `any` are useful builtins!) then append the `name` to the list of `good_names`
- return the list of good names to the caller.

I have also included a couple of function calls that mimick the OP examples.

#### The *possibly* much awaited one-liner

`s` is for *suspects*...

```
def s(n,m):return [g for l in [len(m)] for g in n if len(g)<=l and all([c.lower() in w.lower() for c,w in zip(g,m)])]
```